# Can you use RAW Github Gists in <link href=""/>?

Tags: github, gist

I'm trying to use CSS I saved in Gist, but can't make it work. No error in the console or anything but the file is not being loaded. Can Gist be used in a way I'm trying to use it? I'm debugging on https://localhost.

```
<link href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[link_to_my_file].css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/plain" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: It's odd that there is nothing at all in the console.  Look at the network request for your CSS file.  What does it return?

Comment: Hmm there was no request for my CSS file. After I changed `type="text/css"` this error was logged: `Refused to apply style from 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[link_to_my_file].css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: Without sample code to try, it's hard to say.  Try changing the URL to something that does not exist, even a different site, and see if you get something different.  If there's any change, then there *mist* have been a request.  I suspect though that the gist site simply doesn't support this, which means you'd need to find a different site to host your CSS or include it in your own site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't going to work.  GitHub serves most files as plain text (MIME type `text/plain`) and to prevent attacks browsers require a correct MIME type (in your case, `text/css`).  GitHub doesn't let you customize the MIME type for this and they really don't want you using the raw file endpoints as your own private CDN.

If you want to use the CSS from your Gist in a website, clone the repository or create an archive and copy the file into your repository when building the website.